# Get Selected Value of dropdown without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdown outside the html table generated by PHP code. I have submit button in this table
 as explained by following code.

```
 <!doctype html>
            Select Year:
                   <select name=\"year\" id=\"year\"  style="width: 200px">
                      <option value=\"2014\">2014</option>
                      <option value=\"2015\">2015</option>
                    </select>

                Select Trimester: 
                    <select name=\"trimester\" id=\"trimester\" style="width: 200px">
                        <option value=\"1st\">1st</option>
                        <option value=\"2nd\">2nd</option>
                        <option value=\"3rd\">3rd</option>
                    </select> 

<?php
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                      $ict_id= $row['id'];
                      $name= $row['name'];
          echo "<tr><form name=\"form$id\" id=\"form$id\"><td>".$name."</td>

        <td>
          <select name=\"absent$id\" id=\"absent$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name=\"creative$id\" id=\"creative$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name=\"problem$id\" id=\"problem$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

    <td>
    <input type=\"button\" name=\"submit$id\"  id=\"submit$id\" value=\"Submit\"      onclick=\"getVal(this.id)\">
?>
```

On clicking this  button it loads following  javascript function.

```
function getVal(clicked_id){

}
```

My problem is how can I get the selected value of year and trimester and use inside the getVal function .

Any helps are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

To get the selected Text of Id year and trimester

```
function getVal(clicked_id){

 $('#year :selected').text();

 $('#trimester :selected').text();
}
```

To get the selected Value

```
 function getVal(clicked_id){
  $('#year').val();

 $('#trimester').val();
}
```

Comment: Year and Trimester isn't enclosed in form and it doesn't have submit form as well. Can I use value of year and trimester within the fuction that is triggered by another submit button

Comment: @stackuser , please Edit the question Or Ask new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery val function

```
function getVal(){
  $('#year').val();
  $('#trimester').val();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery, you can fetch it like

```
function getVal(){

 var ddlYear= $('#year').val();
 var ddlTrimester= $('#trimester').val();    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See as you are GETTING value You need to return data , its logical thing.Not to just store in variable.

```
function getValYear(){
 return $('#year').val();
}

function getValTrimester(){
 return $('#trimester').val();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your other question about getting UI elements into table cells before you deleted it.  It seemed like an extension of this question, so I figured I'd post it here.  I was thinking you may want to consider moving the select boxes and ui elements **visually** into the table cells.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1dkcqjz/) I made before you removed your question and figured you may want to see it.  Seems somewhat relevant to what you're asking here, if only a few steps further along in development...

```
$("select").addClass("hidden");

$("#abc-td").on("click focus", function (){
    var $offset = $(this).offset();
    var $top = $offset.top - 9,
        $left = $offset.left - 9,
        $height = $(this).outerHeight(),
        $width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $("#abc").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: $top,
        left: $left,
        height: $height,
        width: $width
    }).removeClass("hidden").focus();
});
```